# Problem getting the displayed text to constantly update like a timer

Tags: python, macos

The variable age is the thing I am trying to constantly update when it is in the Mac OS menu bar, and I can't figure out where to put a while loop without it breaking the code. Thanks

```
from datetime import *
import rumps

birthyear = int(input('enter year '))
birthmonth = (int(input('enter month '))/12)
bday = int(input('enter day '))/365
birthdate = birthyear + birthmonth + bday
age = str(0)
def calcage():
    global now
    global age
    now = datetime.now()
    ct = (int(now.strftime("%H")) / 24 + int(now.strftime('%M')) / 1440 + int(now.strftime('%S')) / 86400) / 365
    curtotal = int(datetime.today().year) + int(datetime.today().month) / 12 + int(datetime.today().day) / 365 + ct
    age = str(curtotal - birthdate)

class lifetimer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        global now
        calcage()
        self.app = rumps.App("Life Timer", str(age))
    def run(self):
        self.app.run()
app = lifetimer()
app.run()
```

Comment: The `rumps` module that you're using seems to have a `Timer` class that's exactly what you need to periodically update the text.

Comment: @jasonharper do you mind showing me an example of how timer is used? I can't find any examples online and I just started using rumps

Comment: @kream Take a look at the [example](https://github.com/jaredks/rumps/blob/master/examples/example_timers.py) in the repo.